# Beginning Java : Finding the greatest number out of a list

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that prompts the user for three numbers and the program is supposed to say what number is the greatest. I didn't want to do a bunch of "System.out.print" in the if and else if statements. The error according to the debugger is that "greatest" and "greatest1" have not been initialized.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class number1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double a, b, c;
        double greatest, greatest1;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter one number :");
        a  = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter another number :"); 
        b  = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter a third number :");
        c  = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if(a > b && a > c) {
            greatest = a;
        } //end of if statement

        else if(b > a && b > c){   
            greatest = b;
        }

        else if(c > a && c > b) { 
            greatest = c;
        }
        else if(a==b && c < a) {
            greatest = a;
            greatest1 = b;

        }

        else if(a==c && b < a) {
            greatest = a;
            greatest1 = c;
        }

        else if(b==c && a < b) {
            greatest = b;
            greatest1 = c;
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("All of the numbers are greatest");
        }
        System.out.print("The greatest number is: " +greatest+ "and" +greatest1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, the others have already point out the problem. I am going to point out that you can find the biggest number out of three number by just doing :

```
biggest = Math.max(a, Math.max(b,c));
```

You can replace all the conditionals in your code.

Imagine that you want the max of a set of integers (*e.g.,* an array of ints). You can do something like:

```
biggest = array[0]; // initialize max to the first number of the set
```

iterate over the set and checking the max:

```
for(int i = 1; i < array.size; i++) 
   biggest = Math.max(biggest,array[i]);
```

or with Java Streams:

```
Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsDouble()
```

You can also make your own max function, for your case can the following:

```
public double maxDouble (double a, double b){
       if(a > b) return a;
       else return b;
}
```

You can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) more detailed information about the Math class and their methods (such as [public static double max(double a,double b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-).

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, you need to make sure `greatest` and `greatest1` are always assigned to a value.  What would happen if it went into this code block:

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
    greatest = a;
} //end of if statement
```

`greatest1` would not be assigned so when it printed it out in the last statement that says

```
System.out.print("The greatest number is: " + greatest + "and" + greatest1);
```

It's giving you an error.

Answer (score 1):

Another tip: If you press <kbd>enter</kbd> after entering each number, you should read the newline `\n` after you read each number.

E.g.

```
a  = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Should be changed to

```
a  = keyboard.nextDouble();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take input from keyboard and create a double array and then try below code.

```
double dblArray[] = {24.0,40.2,38.9};
Arrays.sort(dblArray);

System.out.print("The greatest number is: " +dblArray[dblArray.length-1]+ " and " +dblArray[dblArray.length-2]);
```

You can print n greatest numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As a general hint: Initialize with 0:

```
double greatest = 0;
double greatest1 = 0;
```

But be warned, in your case this indicates an error in your code logic.
Fix that logic, otherwise the result will be 0, which can be wrong.

Comment: That would not help, he must fix his logic!

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment just before you posted yours :)